# Is there any control character or hack to prevent simple command line tools from showing subsequent data?

Tags: shell, text-processing, command-line, streams

I'ld like to hide ugly data from being shown by command line tools like `cat` (and maybe simple text editors too) which often get confused by binary data. For example a VT100 terminal sometimes gets misconfigured by binary outputs.

```
<?php
// PHP code shown by text tools on the command line

__halt_compiler();

// here some fake EOF mark for simple text processing tools
// hidden ugly data
```

Can *end of file* be spoofed to simple stream-based text viewer tools, especially to the linux command line tools (but maybe also to some windows tools)?

I am looking for a solution from within the mixed text/binary file, so that other people using `cat` or similar do not get trash on their screen.

Comment: Just use the "considered harmful" `cat -v`. It's not clear what you mean by "spoofing" eof -- you could just `sed /ugly/q file`.

Comment: I see, the question hasn't been clear enough yet. I am thinking about a solution from within a mixed text / binary file.

Comment: @mosvy However, many thanks. That's a good suggestion for my own daily work on the command line.

Comment: @mosvy By "spoofing eof" I mean some control character or similar indicating *end of file/end of text stream* to simple text-processing tools without affecting the file system or any binary tool.

Comment: perhaps you need to use a terminal that does not "understand" control codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One 'solution' would be to use the alternative screen buffer which many (but not all) terminals support. Consider the following command:

```
printf "Hello, \e[?1049h ABCDEFG \e[?1049l World\n"
```

On a terminal supporting alternative screen buffers, you would see

```
Hello,  World!
```

possibly with a very sudden flash of the terminal.

The `\e[?1049h` sequence will cause the terminal to switch to the alternative screen buffer, where everything printed afterwards will end up. The `\e[?1049l` sequence switches back to the main screen buffer.

An example with php:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
// Nothing to see here...^[[?1049h
echo ", World!\n";
//^[[?1049l
?>
```

where `^[` represends the escape character.

The alternative screen buffer is used by many programs which like to create terminal user interfaces, but want to restore the contents of the terminal after closing. This is how *less* can display contents using the entire window, but upon exiting, all of the previous commands are still visible. If you have *unbuffer* installed, you can verify this:

```
$ unbuffer less -f /dev/null | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 3f31 3034 3968 1b3d 0d0d 1b5b 4b1b  .[?1049h.=...[K.
```

as you can see, the first thing printed is `\x1b[?1049h` which causes the terminal to switch screen buffers.

This would not work on any editor (that I'm aware of) since most editors do not attempt to display non-printable characters.

Comment: Could you also explain what the alternative buffer actually is for? Can there occur any side-effects? I guess one could flush the buffer later onto screen as well with some escape sequence which might be the intended default usage?

Comment: And do you know which terminal standard does define this? VT52, VT100?

Comment: Great answer! Actually I did not expect, somebody would come up with a solution very close to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I've edited the answer to mention usage. I'm not sure what you mean by side effects. If the terminal was already on the alternative screen buffer then the final `^[[1049l` will cause it to return to the main screen buffer

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I'm not sure about terminal standards, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) lists it as a "popular private sequence"

Comment: The explanation given is incorrect: when xterm saves/restores the cursor while switching, it (as a side-effect) saves/restores some of the video attributes.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I'm not too sure what you mean, is the restoring a side effect?

Comment: The cursor *position* is intentionally restored, but the other features are a side-effect that wasn't noticed at the time.  It's [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) feature, at any rate.